# Outlook 2016--all email arrives marked read

Tags: email, outlook

I'm running Outlook 2016 (MSO 16.0.4266.1001 32-bit) on Windows 10 Professional (currently at version 1903).

I've recently switched to Outlook as the company I work for will be consolidating all email on Exchange and Outlook.

I've had some challenges, but most everything is working correctly now. The one exception is every message I receive shows up in my inbox as read. I receive email via the Exchange server, from an internal network POP3 server, and an external POP3 server. In the Reading Pane options, both the options to mark items as read are ***not*** checked. It's all delivered to the same inbox in the same data file. It doesn't matter which way I receive a message--they all show up as read. Hence, I have no indication of what I've read nor do I get notice that I have new email.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-is-automatically-marking-emails-as-read/b5597026-6e95-4bfd-8645-754c195f9627

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I do not use Outlook Web Access nor a mobile device to access the email.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution to my problem.

I also started to get a dialog telling me:
"Your mailbox has been temporarily moved on Microsoft Exchange server. A temporary mailbox exists, but might not have all of your previous data.
You can connect to the temporary mailbox or work offline with all of your old data.
If you choose to work with your old data, you cannot send or receive e-mail messages."

"Important Do not choose to connect to the temporary mailbox. This may cause data loss."

If I can't send or receive email, what's the point, eh? So I was using the temporary and hadn't lost any data. Searching for a solution to this problem, I found the following link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3197025/your-mailbox-has-been-temporarily-moved-on-microsoft-exchange-server

The post lists 2 workarounds. The second one is what worked for me. In summary you remove the old profile and create a new one (after backing up the data). This solved the message about a temporary mailbox and also fixed the problem where email arrive marked as read.